# Unable to convert an array back to string by using join(" ")

Tags: javascript, arrays

I initially have a string whose words first letter I want to capitalize. After capitalization, I'm unable to convert the array back to string.
What's wrong here?

```
const name = 'This is a beautiful day';
console.log(name)
const capitalizedName = name.split(' ');
for (let i = 0; i < capitalizedName.length; i++) {
capitalizedName[i] =
  capitalizedName[i][0].toUpperCase() + capitalizedName[i].substr(1);
}
capitalizedName.join(' ');
console.log(capitalizedName);
```

The output:-

```
This is a beautiful day
[ 'This', 'Is', 'A', 'Beautiful', 'Day' ]
```

Output that I was expecting:-

```
This is a beautiful day
This Is A Beautiful Day
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.join()` _returns_ the joined string. You're not doing anything with its return value.

Comment: Please try this: `console.log(('This is a beautiful day').split(' ').map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1)).join(' '));`. The `capitalizedName.join(' ');` returns a string - it does not mutate the array `capitalizedName`. So, if you simply say `console.log(capitalizedName.join(' '));` - it should provide the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reassign the variable `capitalizedName` as a string

```
capitalizedName = capitalizedName.join(' ');
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't reassign capitalizedName after join function

you can also use map function on split array to manipulate word each other

```js
const name = 'This is a beautiful day';
console.log(name);
let capitalized = name.split(' ')
   .map(word => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1))
   .join(' ');
console.log(capitalized);
```